# debugging php on a live server using var_dump or echo

Tags: php, apache, http, post, server

Im using PHP on a localhost server. Im using the apache server preinstalled with OS X Yosemite, with phpmyadmin.

Im sending it some post data through an app I'm testing but want to be able to view the (presumed JSON Dictionary) data that is being received at in the $_POST variable.

Since the script is running server side and only executes on receiving the http post request how do i verify what is being received in the post variable, or any other variable for that matter.

When running a script in a browser or in an ide i can use the terminal output but because I want to know the format in which the post data is being received i need a way to view the output in response to the received data.

i am aware of var_dump and echo but when the file is running on a live server i don't know how/where can i view the output of these commands.

Comment: Write to a log file?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); die(); The output will appear as the webpage.

Comment: @Quintile on a live server that would produce less than ideal results.

Comment: oops, for some reason I thought he meant on localhost. My bad!

Answer (score 4):

Since I dont have the rep to add a comment, I think that @tuananh is right.

The easiest thing would to use either `file_put_contents()` or `error_log()` to write it to a simple file that you can then `tail -f` on the server.

[error_log docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Also, just an addition to this, functions such as var_dump that output directly to the output stream (doesn't have a return option such as print_r) you can capture that output with `ob_start()` before the var_dump and `ob_get_clean()` to get that output as a string. You could then pass that string to your logging method of choice.

Comment: OK thanks guys! from my reading i need to enable error logs in the php.ini file on my system. so ill locate that and get to it!

Comment: file_put_contents worked for me when var_dump did not create output